# Bootstrap 5 ESM and Webpack Encore

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, webpack-encore

I am getting some troubles with Webpack Encore & Bootstrap 5 ESM.

First, bootstrap global variable is not available but the BS' documentation is referring to.

Second, bootstrap is not loading its jquery plugins, so any existing usage is broken.

So, how to do to fix these issues ?

In my app.js

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.esm.js';
```

NB: I am using BS 5 ESM to get a compatibility with modules, especially with Stimulus controllers & popperjs.
These technologies are great but together, this is hell.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to import bootstrap like this in `app.js`:

```js
import 'bootstrap';
```

in Webpack Encore you get something like this:

```js
/* harmony import */ var bootstrap__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__ = __webpack_require__(/*! bootstrap */ "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.esm.js");
```

as you can see it takes you to `bootstrap.esm.js` automatically.